# Python3 itertools.permutations on dict of lists?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, iterator, permutation

Say I have a dict of lists.  Each key represents a variable and each list represents the possible values that variable can have.

```
myBools = [ True, False ]
myInts = [ -3, 0, 4 ]
myFloats = [ -2.2, 0.0, 1.1 ]

myDict = {
    'aBool': myBools,
    'bInt': myInts,
    'cFloat': myFloats,
}
```

Now, how do I get a list of dicts for all permutations of aBool, bInt and cFloat?  Each list entry will be a dict.  Each dict will have a unique set of values representing one permutation.

Expected:

```
myPermList = [
    { 'aBool': True, 'bInt': -3, 'cFloat': -2.2 },
    { 'aBool': True, 'bInt': -3, 'cFloat': 0.0 },
    { 'aBool': True, 'bInt': -3, 'cFloat': 1.1 },
    # ...
    { 'aBool': False, 'bInt': 4, 'cFloat': -2.2 },
    { 'aBool': False, 'bInt': 4, 'cFloat': 0.0 },
    { 'aBool': False, 'bInt': 4, 'cFloat': 1.1 },
]
```

I am having trouble trying to figure out if itertools.permutations can help me here and if so, how to set up the call.

The intended use of such a technique is to help automate testing of some other functions in a comprehensive and systematic way so that I can extend lists to include good as well as bad data to test both correct functionality in the case of good data and proper error handling in the case of bad data.

myBools, myInts and myFloats will represent tests for various data types that can be reused.  These may be mixed in the future (i.e. test int and float data).  But the code as written represents the simplest and most generic input and output data structures that I could think of.

Edit Note 1:

I found a limitation in the way I initially arranged the problem which did not allow a level of automation that I had intended.  The initial definition of reusable sets left the set names as variables.  However, that might be pertinent metadata in the future and would be easier to access if stored as dictionary keys rather than trying to extract using code analysis or metaprogramming techniques.

Subsequently, I pick a more descriptive name for myDict, e.g. myOptions.  Then, I more explicitly demonstrate the intent with additional sets and options.  Now if I wish to analyze options with extra code, it is much easier.  This doesn't really change the initial problem, just includes more manipulation to set up the itertools function (product or permutation) that will be utilized.

Finally, as I am apparently not looking for a permutation but a Cartesian product (thanks for the correction!), I will store the result is a more accurately and simply named myOptsList.

```
mySets = {
    'myBools1': [ True, False ],
    'myInts1': [ -3, 0, 4 ],
    'myFloats1': [ -2.2, 0.0, 1.1 ],
    'myInts2': [ -500, -250, 0, 250, 500 ],
    'myFloats2': [ -88.8, -44.4, -0.0, +0.0, 44.4, 88.8 ],
    # ... arbitrary number of sets
}

myOptions = {
    'aBool': mySets[ 'myBools1' ],
    'bInt': mySets[ 'myInts1' ],
    'cFloat': mySets[ 'myFloats1' ],
    'dInt': mySets[ 'myInts1' ],
    'eInt': mySets[ 'myInts2' ],
    'fInt': mySets[ 'myInts1' ],
    'gFloat': mySets[ 'myFloats2' ],
    # ... arbitary number of options,
    #     potentially reusing sets
}

# Set up parameters and find Cartesian product

myOptsList = [
    { 'aBool': True, 'bInt': -3, 'cFloat': -2.2, 'dInt': -3, 'eInt': -500, 'fInt': -3, 'gFloat': -88.8 },
    # ...
    { 'aBool': False, 'bInt': 4, 'cFloat': 1.1, 'dInt': 4, 'eInt': 500, 'fInt': 4, 'gFloat': 88.8 },
]
```

Comment: You just want available options? Instead of using `lists` in `mySets` use a `set`. We don't get updates when you update a question. Your update was more specific but it doesnt bring new attention to your quesiton.

Answer (score 0):

It would be faster if you didn't put it in a `dict` first but this solution works.  This is dynamic as well, if you add a entry and list to the dict the solution will still work as intended.

```
from itertools import product # This will get all permutations

myBools = [ True, False ]
myInts = [ -3, 0, 4 ]
myFloats = [ -2.2, 0.0, 1.1 ]

myDict = {
    'aBool': myBools,
    'bInt': myInts,
    'cFloat': myFloats,
} 

# First we need to grab the keys and values
keys, vals = list(myDict.keys()), list(myDict.values())

# Then we find all permutations for those values
permutations = list(product(*vals))

# Finally we can create out list of dicts
result = [{keys[index]: entry[index] for index in range(len(entry))} for entry in permutations]
# You combine the above to statements into a single list comprehension 
# if you want but I though this way was more readable.

for x in result:
    print(x)
```

**Output:**

```
{'aBool': True, 'bInt': -3, 'cFloat': -2.2}
{'aBool': True, 'bInt': -3, 'cFloat': 0.0}
{'aBool': True, 'bInt': -3, 'cFloat': 1.1}
{'aBool': True, 'bInt': 0, 'cFloat': -2.2}
{'aBool': True, 'bInt': 0, 'cFloat': 0.0}
{'aBool': True, 'bInt': 0, 'cFloat': 1.1}
{'aBool': True, 'bInt': 4, 'cFloat': -2.2}
{'aBool': True, 'bInt': 4, 'cFloat': 0.0}
{'aBool': True, 'bInt': 4, 'cFloat': 1.1}
{'aBool': False, 'bInt': -3, 'cFloat': -2.2}
{'aBool': False, 'bInt': -3, 'cFloat': 0.0}
{'aBool': False, 'bInt': -3, 'cFloat': 1.1}
{'aBool': False, 'bInt': 0, 'cFloat': -2.2}
{'aBool': False, 'bInt': 0, 'cFloat': 0.0}
{'aBool': False, 'bInt': 0, 'cFloat': 1.1}
{'aBool': False, 'bInt': 4, 'cFloat': -2.2}
{'aBool': False, 'bInt': 4, 'cFloat': 0.0}
{'aBool': False, 'bInt': 4, 'cFloat': 1.1}
```

Comment: Please provide more detail to what you are trying to actually do in your question (or what you want to actually achieve). **Including an example**. I don't quiet understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you do not want permutations. You want Cartesian product.

```
from itertools import product
myPermList = [{'aBool':c[0],'bInt':c[1],'cFloat':c[2]} for c in list(product(myBools,myInts,myFloats))]
```

**output:**

```
[{'aBool': True, 'bInt': -3, 'cFloat': -2.2},
 {'aBool': True, 'bInt': -3, 'cFloat': 0.0},
 {'aBool': True, 'bInt': -3, 'cFloat': 1.1},
 {'aBool': True, 'bInt': 0, 'cFloat': -2.2},
 {'aBool': True, 'bInt': 0, 'cFloat': 0.0},
 {'aBool': True, 'bInt': 0, 'cFloat': 1.1},
 {'aBool': True, 'bInt': 4, 'cFloat': -2.2},
 {'aBool': True, 'bInt': 4, 'cFloat': 0.0},
 {'aBool': True, 'bInt': 4, 'cFloat': 1.1},
 {'aBool': False, 'bInt': -3, 'cFloat': -2.2},
 {'aBool': False, 'bInt': -3, 'cFloat': 0.0},
 {'aBool': False, 'bInt': -3, 'cFloat': 1.1},
 {'aBool': False, 'bInt': 0, 'cFloat': -2.2},
 {'aBool': False, 'bInt': 0, 'cFloat': 0.0},
 {'aBool': False, 'bInt': 0, 'cFloat': 1.1},
 {'aBool': False, 'bInt': 4, 'cFloat': -2.2},
 {'aBool': False, 'bInt': 4, 'cFloat': 0.0},
 {'aBool': False, 'bInt': 4, 'cFloat': 1.1}]
```

Comment: Nesting questions complicates understanding of the original problem and its subsequent developments. Then, my suggestion is to ask a new question. If I understand your updated problem, it should be easy to solve it. ;)